# How to convert SwiftUI PreviewProvider to #Preview?

Tags: swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View{
    
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text(scrum.title)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                Label("\(scrum.attendees.count)", systemImage: "person.3")
                Spacer()
                Label("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes)", systemImage: "clock")
                    .labelStyle(.trailingIcon)
            }
            .font(.caption)
       }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
    }
}

 struct CardView_Preview: PreviewProvider{
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
    static var previews: some View{
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

In this code I want to convert the `PreviewProvider` into `#Preview`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Preview{
    CardView(scrum: DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include some setup in your `#Preview`, but remember that it's not a `@ViewBuilder` block. So if you have multiple statements, you need to explicitly return the view to display:

```swift
#Preview {
  let scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]

  return CardView(scrum: scrum)
           .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
}
```

To modify the layout, you replace the old style modifiers with traits within the macro declaration:

```swift
#Preview(traits: .fixedLayout(width: 400, height: 60)) {
  let scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]

  return CardView(scrum: scrum)
           .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
}
```